# Method of energy functions to show boundedness of 2nd Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, upper-lower-bounds, bounded-variation

[image]

I made the following system from the typical $x_1=x, x_2=x'$ transformation:

$x_1'=x_2\\x_2'=\sin^2(x_1)-x_2\cos^2(x_1)$

I then used the general energy function

$E(t,x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2}(x_2)^2+\int_{0}^{x_1}g(s)ds$ when $x''+f(x)x'+g(x)=0$.

Here, $E(t,x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2}(x_2)^2-\int_{0}^{x_1}\sin^2(s)ds$

And $\frac{dE}{dt}=-(x_2)^2\cos^2(x_1)≤0$ after applying the FTC, substituting, and cancelling terms.

So the system is always dissipating energy, that is, for any time t, $E(t)≤E(0)$.

I want to show the boundedness of $x_2$, that is, $|x_2(t)|≤K,$ for some constant $K$ and $t≥0$.

I get to the inequality: $\frac{1}{2}(x_2(t))^2-\int_{0}^{x_1(t)}\sin^2(s)ds≤\frac{1}{2}(x_2(0))^2-\frac{x_1(0)}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x_1(0))$

Or if you prefer: $\frac{1}{2}(x_2(t))^2-\frac{x_1(t)}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x_1(t))≤\frac{1}{2}(x_2(0))^2-\frac{x_1(0)}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x_1(0))$.

I cannot figure out how to remove the terms with $x_1(t)$ to isolate $|x_2(t)|$ while also keeping the ≤ inequality...

Note: $-\frac{x_1(t)}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x_1(t))<0$, for all $x_1(t)$

Any help?

Update: I've since shifted my efforts to first showing $x_1$ is bounded and then moving terms around in the inequality to show $x_2$ is bounded. I think this might be the only way to do it, but I'm not confident my method was correct...

Comment: While $E'(t) < 0$, there's no reason that $E>0$, so there's no reason to believe the energy will remain bounded.  I think your update might work, given you can say something like $|x-x(0)| \leq t\sup(x'(t))$ which should let you bound $x$ between two functions of $t$.

Comment: It would be easier to use that $|x_2'|\le 1+|x_2|$, which implies $\|x'\|\le 1+\|x\|$, so the equation is linearly bounded. This gives $\|x(t)\|\le e^{|t|}(1+\|x(0)\|)-1$ (by Grönwall or some directer argument), which proves the unrestricted existence of $x=(x_1,x_2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a more general idea of "energy function" then start with the standard
$$
E=\frac12(x'^2+x^2)
$$
with time derivative
$$
E'=x'(x''+x)=x'(-\cos^2xx'+\sin^2x+x)\le x'(\sin^2x+x)
$$
Using mean inequalities it follows that
$$
E'\le x'(1+x)\le |x'|\sqrt{2(1+x^2)}\le\frac{1+x'^2+x^2}{\sqrt2}\\
E'\le \frac1{\sqrt2}+\sqrt2E\\
$$
which then integrates on $[0,\infty)$ to
$$
 1+2E(t)\le e^{\sqrt2t}(1+2E_0)
$$
Thus as long as the solution exists it remains exponentially bounded, and can thus be extended obeying the same bound. No divergence in finite time is possible.